# mips number of clock cycles and how improving code

Tags: assembly, mips, cycle, clock, mips32

I'm really new in MIPS and I have these questions which I found so many dissimil answers for them ... if someone can help, it would be great. Thanks

*How many clock cycles does this code take?*

```
#Macro Instructions
li  $t0, 32         #  1 or 2 cycles ?      
                    #                lui $at, Upper 16-bits of value 
                    #                ori Rd, $at, Lower 16-bits of value
                    #                -----------------------------------
                    #                ori Rt, $0, value
                    #
                    #  Which set of instructions will be executed?


div $t2, $t2, $t0   #  41 cycles?          
                    #                bne Rt, $0,
                    #                break $0
                    #                ok: div Rs, Rt
                    #                mflo Rd

#Integer Instruction

lw  $t2, 0($t13)    #  1  cycles?
sw  $t2, 0($t3)     #  1  cycles?
```

How those 4 lines of codes can be significantly improved? by avoiding to use Macros or ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `li  $t0, 32`

This one you can easily check by disassembling your executable or object file. Use `objdump` from your MIPS toolchain with the `-d` or `-D` option. I would guess that the assembler is smart enough not to generate a `lui` for such a small value.

---

- `div $t2, $t2, $t0`

Since you're you're dividing by a power of two (32), there's a much faster way of doing this: shift right by `log2(divisor)` bits (i.e. 5 bits):

```
srl $t2, $t2, 5   # if $t2 is unsigned
```

or

```
sra $t2, $t2, 5   # if $t2 is signed
```